# docker login - Keep Session Alive on CI Server - Stay Logged In

Tags: docker

I am running the dockerd service on my CI server. As the user the CI server runs as (via SSH), I am doing `docker login my_host:my_port`, then entering the username and password it asks for.

The login succeeds, and the jobs run and successfully connect to our repository. But eventually, the logged session is invalidated for some reason, and it becomes necessary to SSH back into the box and re-do the login.

How can I stay permanently logged in, or keep the session alive?

Comment: it is not typically behavior. When you log in, the command stores encoded credentials in `$HOME/.docker/config.json`
when session is invalidated is `config.json` exist?

Comment: Yes, config.json still exists, but the encoded credentials are gone.